# Displaying PDF with Java Play! 2 framework

Tags: pdf, playframework, playframework-2.0

I generate PDFs in Java play 2 (using external resources) and store them at the root of my project in a pdfs/ folder.

Now, I'm not that good in java and I can't manage to display the PDF without putting it in the public folder (which can't be because it is not secured). So my question is:

How to display a PDF file in the client browser without putting it in the public folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution: 
`return ok(new FileInputStream("pdfs/doc.pdf")).as("application/pdf");`

Comment: You should not have to store them in the filesystem, but send the output stream directly.

Comment: I had to. I need to store the PDF on the server anyways, it was a need.

Comment: this is what i looked for. Thanks a lot @user2099857

Answer (score 3):

Just send the binary representation, and specify the PDF content type:

```
public static Result createPDF() {
  byte[] pdfAsBinary = ...
  response().setContentType("application/pdf");
  return ok(pdfAsBinary);
}
```

Comment: This thing is I don't know how to get the pdf file... It is in /pdfs/doc.pdf.

I try to use `controllers.Assets.at("pdfs", "doc.pdf");` but it returns an action type i don't know what to do with it